# All elements in list in for loop are the same

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop

I'm writing a function to iterate a list of values into an other list containing dictionaries, but in the end I get a list of repeated values.

```
def createlayer():
    layerdxf = {"2": "",
                "70": "64",
                "62": "0",
                "6": "CONTINUOUS"}
    lr = ['grey', 'green', 'red', 'orange']
    lrys = []
    for la in lr:
        layerdxf.update({'2': la})
        el = {"LAYER": layerdxf}
        lrys.append(el)
    return lrys
```

The function returns:

```
[
{'LAYER': {'2': 'orange', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}},
{'LAYER': {'2': 'orange', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}},
{'LAYER': {'2': 'orange', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}},
{'LAYER': {'2': 'orange', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}}
]
```

When should return:

```
[
{'LAYER': {'2': 'grey', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}},
{'LAYER': {'2': 'green', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}},
{'LAYER': {'2': 'red', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}},
{'LAYER': {'2': 'orange', '70': '64', '62': '0', '6': 'CONTINUOUS'}}
]
```

Thanks,

JA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is a mutable object in Python. Consider this:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1}
>>> d2 = d
>>> d
{'a': 1}
>>> d2
{'a': 1}
>>> d is d2
True
```

Both `d` and `d2` refer to the same object. You can make changes to the dictionary through either variable name, but since they both refer to the same object, changes made via one variable are seen via the other variable:

```
>>> d['b'] = 2
>>> d2
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

So this is what is happening in your code but, instead of having multiple variables that refer to the same object, you have elements of a list that refer to the same object. Therefore the last modification to the dictionary (setting the colour to orange) is seen by all list elements.

To fix it, make a copy of the dictionary. For such a simple dictionary you can use `dict.copy()` before updating the dictionary:

```
for la in lr:
    d = layerdxf.copy()
    d.update({'2': la})
    lrys.append({"LAYER": d})
```

Another more succinct way is to use a list comprehension:

```
def createlayer():
    lr = ['grey', 'green', 'red', 'orange']
    return [{"2": la, "70": "64", "62": "0", "6": "CONTINUOUS"} for la in lr]
```